# EditText added is not a TextInputEditText. Please switch to using that class instead. How to resolve?

Tags: android, android-studio

How to resolve error?
EditText added is not a TextInputEditText. Please switch to using that class instead

```
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Read more about TextInputLayout [here](https://material.io/develop/android/components/text-fields/)

As the documents in material.io suggest its better to use the new `TextInputEditText` instead of `EditText` because using the old one can mess up the background.

I suggest upgrading your them to **Material**.
It has lots of cool stuff (More in the link)

It supports:

- Start or End Icon
- Animations for hint
- Error/Helper Text and ...

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/email">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: @DarM Add this to your build.gradle (app-level) `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0`

Comment: It did't help(((((((

Comment: Did you also change `TextInputEditText` to `com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText`? I updated my answer about 5min ago.

Comment: Yes, He has to do this to fix the issue but `TextColor` and `hint` should be in the `TextInputLayout` tag instead of `TextInputEditText`.

Comment: @LalitFauzdar Thanks, Good points but he/she should read docs before implementation. `hint` can be both on TextInputLayout and TextInputEditText

Comment: Yes, but as Official docs prefer, it should be in `TextInputLayout` because it moves to Top when a character is entered and that doesn't happen when it is used inside `TextInputEditText`. Also, the theme/style of `TextInputLayout` doesn't effect the hint if it's used in `TextInputEditText`.

Comment: @LalitFauzdar Exactly if you need the animation you should always put it on `TextInputLayout` but there was a case I didn't need the animation and put it on `TextInputEditText`. I edited my answer and put it on `TextInputLayout` for best practice.

Comment: @abstractArrow  inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);  
Is it necessary to change here too?

Comment: @DarM Yes you need to change your cast and variable to `TextInputEditText`

Comment: I changed. it didn’t work, apparently there is an error that I can’t notice :( Thanks for the help

Comment: @DarM Are you using a Material Components Theme in your app?